# Undefined method `rails_safe_buffer_class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, eco

In my rails project i'm using [haml_assets](https://github.com/carezone/haml_assets) gem

The content of `registration.jst.eco.haml` file:

```
= form_for :contact, url: "javascript_not_working", html: {:class => :edit_contact, :method => :put} do |f|
  = f.label :name, "Name"
  = f.text_field :name, class: 'text required', value: '{{name}}'
```

When I'm running jasmine tests I've got this error in the browser:

```
TypeError: Object true has no method 'replace'
  (in .../app/assets/templates/users/registration.jst.eco.haml)
```

and in console:

```
ERROR: compiling .../app/assets/templates/users/registration.jst.eco.haml 
  RAISED undefined method `rails_safe_buffer_class' for Haml::Util:Module
```

I even tried just only helper:

```
= form_for :contact
```

and error the same

How to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: Have u tried `autofocus: 'true'` OR `autofocus: 'autofocus'` ?

Comment: I delete autofocus and it didn't help